Bootstrapping issue. Chef server
Hi I am getting same ssh password prompt while bootstrapping node (ec2 instance) to the chef server. What specifically can be done to resolve this ? Stuck in this step from past 2 days.
Tried few steps that were mentioned here in the previous articles related to this topic but it seems that it is not working for me.
